# Flags on multiple comments for one post

Tags: discussion, flagging

Sometimes I see several comments to one post which are equally obsolete/to chatty/...

I don't know how the flag review queue is organized, so

what is simpler for reviewers? Should I

- flag one comment with a custom flag mentioning all affected comments?
- flag each comment individually?

Comment: From experience I can say that flagging one comment is enough.

Comment: [Recent discussion on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227454/213575) from a fellow moderator about this.

Comment: Sorry, was a fellow severed head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If most (or all) of the comments need to be removed it's generally easier to custom flag one and explain. Example:

> All these comments are (obsolete, off-topic, etc)

or:

> All these comments except the first two should be removed for reason xyz

If it is a particular mess you can just say:

> These comments are a mess. Most of them can probably be removed

Or if it is a small mess, flag the individual comments that need to go.

Ultimately if you flag individual comments they will be grouped together in the queue, so it really doesn't matter which option you choose that much.

---

One thing about the comment handling tools I think I should point out is that they aren't great. We can't mark a comment flag helpful and take no action for example. If you're flagging a borderline comment use custom flag and give an explanation on why you think it needs to be removed. That way your flags won't get declined.

Comment: In the case "they are a mess" sometimes it also helps to talk to a mod in chat. I have seen mods clean out a large number of (rather nasty) comments in a few seconds just simply by asking them. Of course we can flag them *and* ask a mod when necessary.